# javac - Superclasses not found

Tags: java, package, javac

I'm trying to compile a Java project (of a Lisp interpreter) in Unix (Solaris to be specific). My problem is that I have a few classes that extend other classes, but when javac attempts to compile the extended classes, it says it can't find the superclass.

Commands I type:

```
javac -g LispObject.java
javac -g Sexp.java
```

The first one works fine; but the second halts with the following error:

```
Sexp.java:7: Superclass interpreter.LispObject of class interpreter.Sexp not found.
public class Sexp extends LispObject
                          ^
1 error
```

(I don't know if it's very relevant but this is for a class project so I have to use a makefile for the compilation, so I can't use any IDEs for the compilation... which sucks because everything worked fine in NetBeans.)

Code for `LispObject.java`:

```
package interpreter;

public class LispObject extends java.lang.Object
{
   // empty
}
```

Code for `Sexp.java`:

```
package interpreter;

public class Sexp extends LispObject
{
   // body stuff goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `-cp .` to your `javac` calls so that it searches the current directory for already compiled classes. Second call would be:

```
javac -cp . -g Sexp.java
```

Alternatively, give it all your `.java` files in one go:

```
javac -g LispObject.java Sexp.java
```

Generally the best would be to set up a specific build directory (i'll call it /some/dir/build) and use:

```
javac -cp /some/dir/build -d /some/dir/build your_file.java
```

so that the `.class` files don't come polluting your source file directorie(s).

Keep in mind that you should keep your directory structure in sync with your package hierarchy. If your classes are in the `interpreter` package, they should be placed in a directory with that name.

So in this specific instance, your compile command should look like:

```
javac -cp /some/dir/build -d /some/dir/build interpreter/LispObject.java
javac -cp /some/dir/build -d /some/dir/build interpreter/Sexp.java
```

Comment: Giving it all the files at once seems to be working; do you know if there is a way to do that with a makefile?

Comment: the better alternative is to use `-cp` to specify where the built `.class` files are. (and use a `-d build_directory` also, so that the `.class` files don't get mixed up with your `.java` files)

Comment: Sorry for the -1, but this does not address the real problem: that you are building not from the package root directory, but from inside the package hierarchy.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: you are right, the directory structure needs to match the package hierarchy. The specific problem for this question wasn't there though as far as I can tell. Updated my answer in any case to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

you have to compile all the classes in one line if you want the compiler to recognize the superClass or add the generated class to classpath as said by ds_student

Answer (score 0):

The usual package-directory problem.

For compiling classes in packages, put them in a directory corresponding to the package structure, and call `javac` from the root of the hierarchy (or provide the hierarchy root as `-sourcepath`, and the output directory in `-d` and `-classpath`).

```
javac interpreter/LispObject.java
javac interpreter/Sexp.java
```